# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ']' in C:\wamp\www\PICKART1\invoice.php on line 35

Tags: php, fetch

Please help me to find the solution
thanks..
And this is my line 35.

INVOICE

```
    <div id="identity">
    <h6 id="customer-title"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h6><br /><br />    
        <h6 id="address"><?php echo $row['adrs']; ?> 
    Phone: <?php echo $row['phone']; ?></h6>
```

Comment: <h6 id="customer-title"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h6><br /><br />

Comment: Could you add a couple of the preceding lines, too?

Comment: confused, you said on title line 35, now it's on line 33? Maybe you got the wrong line.

Comment: this line of code is alright dear

Comment: sorry about that, but i don't see any errors in this code line..

Comment: It's quite possible that this is an issue on the previous line of PHP code.

Comment: With the given code, the error [cannot be reproduced](http://codepad.org/D24udnfR)